# postgresql how not to show the first result returned st_distance

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that calculates the distance away from a given point, however currently my query returns the point I am actually querying a distance for. How would I prevent site 1 from showing in my results?

Site 1 = 0.00km
site 2 = 0.15km
site 3 = 3.5km

`st_distance(the_geom, st_geomfromtext($geomdistanceaway,27700))::numeric(10,2) AS distanceaway from distancetbl ORDER BY distanceaway asc limit 3`

Comment: If you provide all your SQL, not just a fragment, then a modification could be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html) :

> OFFSET says to skip that many rows before beginning to return rows. OFFSET 0 is the same as omitting the OFFSET clause, and LIMIT NULL is the same as omitting the LIMIT clause.

If you want to skip the first result :

```
st_distance(the_geom, st_geomfromtext($geomdistanceaway,27700))::numeric(10,2) AS distanceaway from distancetbl ORDER BY distanceaway asc limit 3 OFFSET 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A self join would get you what you need.

```
SELECT a.id As FromID
,b.id As ToID
, ST_Distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)::numeric(10.2) As DistanceAway
FROM distancetbl a, distancetbl b
WHERE a.id <> b.id
ORDER BY distanceaway
LIMIT 3
```

Or wrap your current query in a subquery and use a where clause to filter out your 0 distance values

```
SELECT * FROM (
  st_distance(the_geom, st_geomfromtext($geomdistanceaway,27700))::numeric(10,2) AS       
  distanceaway from distancetbl ORDER BY distanceaway asc limit 3) x
WHERE distanceaway > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constraint to the query that removes the basis feature from consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of ways.  The quick and dirty way is to use your current query as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
  [your subquery] AS distance_table
WHERE distanceaway > 0
```

Another way is to reference "distancetbl" twice with aliases in your `FROM` clause and then test against matching site id in your `WHERE` clause:

```
...
FROM "distancetbl" t1, "distancetbl" t2
...
WHERE NOT t1.site_id = t2.site_id
```

The second method would require further modification to your query.